# swift How to convert time string +4:00 to Timezone

Tags: ios, swift, localization, timezone, timestamp

How to convert string to timezone ? For example, I have string:

```
2016.9.5 - 16:36
```

This time is GMT+4, So how to convert to timezone?

Comment: Which timezone you want to convert to ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Yes to which timezone you want to convert?

Answer (score 0):

First Remove '-' from the above string
and then pass the string to below method

```
static func getDateFromString( _ str  : String) -> Date{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm"
    return dateFormatter.date(from: str)!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to convert this string to GMT time:

```
    let str = "2016.9.5 - 16:36"

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT:  4 * 60 * 60)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy.M.d - HH:mm"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: str)!
    print(date) // result : 2016-09-05 12:36:00 +0000
```